# Regarding Java Version

Tags: java

presently there are many application programs developed using recent versions of java.how an end user in a network having old version of Java can be able to see the output? (perspective: different classes includes in new version of Java)

Comment: [OT] I misread "Regarding Java Venison"

Answer (score 1):

For applications that have been developed using recent versions of Java, there's no solution other than having users upgrade their Java runtime to the minimum version required to run the applications.

Note that it is not only the classes in the standard Java library, but also the .class file format has changed in ways that are not backwards compatible with old Java runtimes.

If you develop an application that targets a specific JVM version / Java specification, then you will need to ensure that all future application updates remain backwards compatible with this JVM version / Java specification.

Comment: OK fine.. but is that the user should have java runtime environment in which it should support should all objects that were created with new versions which were not in old version.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't quite understand what you mean here. Could you clarify?

Comment: One opportunity created by an omnipresent network is online software distribution. Java takes advantage of this opportunity by enabling the transmission of binary code in small pieces across networks. This capability can make Java programs easier and cheaper to deliver than programs that are not network- mobile. It can also simplify version control. Because the most recent version of a Java program can be delivered on-demand across a network, you needn't worry about what version your end-users are running. They will always get the most recent version each time they use your program.

Comment: Obviously this is only possible if the application in question remains backwards compatible with the JVM version / Java specification it was originally developed for. For example, if an application was originally written for J2ME / MIDP 1.0, then the developer is responsible for ensuring that all application updates remain compatible with J2ME / MIDP 1.0. An hypothetical application update using features from MIDP 2.0 would not work in devices that only support MIDP 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

If you want are asking how to find out the version of Java you are currently running, you can execute the following on the command line:

```
$java -version
```

Answer (score 0):

OK fine.. but is that the user should have java runtime environment in which it should support should all objects that were created with new versions which were not in old version.